# No puedo compilar tildes en proyecto Maven- IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Estoy teniendo problemas desde hace días cuando en mi proyecto Maven uso tildes.
Cuando escribo la palabra "Trámites", el proyecto de maven que tengo, transforma la "á" en un caracter extraño.

Code:

```
System.out.println("Trámite");
```

aparece en la consola:

`Tr$amite`

estoy usando "$" porque no encuentro la manera de copiar el carácter que me aparece.
Solo para comentar me encuentro usando IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: Pon el encoding del proyecto, y por ende de todos los ficheros, a UTF-8. Luego compila, te saldrán warnings por cada símbolo raro y ya puedes cambiar todas las letras que queras. La clave es UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

En la parte inferior derecha de tu archivo puedes revisar que codificación se está usando actualmente para cada archivo

[image: encoding dialog]

Una vez que seleccionas otra codificación te da dos opciones:

- recargar en la codificación seleccionada (esto no modifica tu archivo, solo trata de leer los caracteres de otra forma)
- convertir (esto cambia la codificación y puede hacer que queden caracteres raros como el famoso *BOM*)

Motivo por el cual primero te recomiendo recargar hasta tenerlo en la codificación que se lea bien y según tus necesidades convertirlo opcionalmente.

La codificación también se puede configurar desde tu `POM`, pero es generalmente independiente de la configuración de tu editor.